# Getting how much money is worth a click on AdMob in runtime

Tags: admob

Can I calculate, at runtime, how much money I earned when a user clicks on a banner that my app displays?

Comment: No, that is all handled on Google's end.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want that number at runtime?

Comment: To score my users.

Answer (score 0):

The CPM is around **$1, or $1 per 1000 Ad impressions**. Clicks I have seen as high **as $0.25**, but its going to vary on the Ad shown obviously.

Essentially my rough guide on income per active user per day based on my very limited experience:

Assuming each user will go through **10 impressions per day/session**. About 10 minutes spent in your app, this is a pretty big assumption and highly app dependent.

**100 active users = 1000 impressions per day = $1**

**10,000 = 100,000 = $100**

**1,000,000 = $10,000**

So on and so forth, just a rough guide. But it will HIGHLY depend on your own app and how long they spend using it per session. Greetings!